# Not able to find Properties file(FileNotfoundException)

Tags: java, ant, selenium, junit4

I am running selenium script using ant task..it is working fine using command prompt..but from ant task, it is not working..How to solve this?

```
 <testcase classname="junit.framework.TestSuite"    name="com.openbravo.test.integration.erp.testsuites.regression.MRC0000_Logging" time="0.0010">
  <error message="config/OpenbravoERPTest.properties (No such file or directory)"   type="java.io.FileNotFoundException">java.io.FileNotFoundException: config/OpenbravoERPTest.properties (No such file or directory)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.&lt;init&gt;(FileInputStream.java:120)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.&lt;init&gt;(FileInputStream.java:79)
 at com.openbravo.test.integration.erp.testscripts.OpenbravoERPTest.loadProperties(OpenbravoERPTest.java:117)
 at com.openbravo.test.integration.erp.testscripts.OpenbravoERPTest.setUpBeforeClass(OpenbravoERPTest.java:105)
 at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
 at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
 at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
 at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
 </error>
 </testcase>
 <system-out><![CDATA[asd
 ]]></system-out>
<system-err><![CDATA[]]></system-err>
</testsuite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the directory containing your config directory is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The path name is relative: `config/OpenbravoERPTest.properties`

Are you sure that you're executing the script from command line in the right directory?